# What is the best way to grant website or application administrators access to their own resources?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am learning how to setup a shared hosting web server.

As a server administrator whose the highest access level in the server, I want to grant my friends as site administrators access to their own sites.

The question is:
What is the best way to setup their accounts and what level of access should be granted to them?

### Edit 1:

I want them to have remote access to their own resources using IIS Manager. By this way, I can mimic a real shared-hosting server.

Comment: Depends upon what they neeed. Is there any specific commands they need to execute, any specific directories on the system, ssh access, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the delegated administration on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a FTP server. And assign the permission to access a folder for a user with user name and password.

Comment: They need more than uploading and downloading privileges.

Comment: Read write and execute permission also can be assigned.

Comment: they need to configure application pool too.